# How to customize the index?

Tags: makeindex

The last page of the index of my book ends with one column and I need that it ends with two columns with the same height.
[image]

How can I customize it?

I'm using the book class.

Comment: ... well, the name of the game is MWE ...

Comment: I don't know hoe to make a MWE for an index because it's made of several references tha are in the whole book.

Comment: Sigh ... See the `imakeidx` package and its `\makeindex` command together with the `columns` option ...

Comment: If I remember correctly, the an index page is lay out in `two-column`  for the standard classes, but that's a guess only

Comment: @ChristianHupfer -- `theindex` certainly uses `twocolumn` for `book`.  `imakeidx` works quite well with "standard" page formatting, and nicely balances the last page.  but it can trash a special format unless the `[original]` option is used, in which case the last page isn't balanced.  nonetheless, `imakeidx` is an excellent, and recommended, tool.  (i don't know how it behaves with the `koma` classes.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Thanks for clearifying... I was too lazy to look into the class codes. So the 'standard' basically is two-column, which makes sense since index entries usually do not use the whole 'paperwidth' and two-column is a nice way to condense the space needed for the entries

Comment: For a MWE try `\documentclass{book} \usepackage{makeidx} \usepackage{testidx} \makeindex \begin{document} \testidx \printindex \end{document}` (replace `makeidx` with `imakeidx` or whatever indexing package you're using). That will generate a document with a multipage index that you can use for testing.

Comment: Hi, everybody.  The Christian and Barbara comments helped me a lot.  I just had to load the imakeidx package and, without any option, it fixed the last page!!!  Thanks for oyur help.  This topic can be closed.